# invalid composer.json metadata packagist

Tags: json, github, composer-php, packagist

When I push new tag to my package to update my composer plugin it returns this error:

> Update of  failed, invalid composer.json metadata
> [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException] Some branches
> contained invalid data and were discarded, it is advised to review the
> log and fix any issues present in branches

[image: one]

Here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "package/name",
    "description": "....",
    "keywords": [
        "...",
        "...",
        "..."
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/username/package-name",
    "type": "composer-plugin",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
        "illuminate/support": "^7.0|^8.0|^9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "composer/composer": "^2.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Package\\Name\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My name",
            "email": "my@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

> And when I run `composer validate` I get `./composer.json is valid`.

As you can see there is no domain name mention whatsoever but error is returning my domain name as invalid which says: `must be an http/https URL`

**Any idea?**

Comment: Please share more details. Are you using the `funding` key in any version of your package?

Comment: @NicoHaase that's all I have. to answer your question: No. `Note:` while I'm getting this error but I also am able to install my package latest tag version when I use `composer require`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the error message in full and with peace of mind (unfortunately you were hiding it from the question by encoding it as image/png).

Don't look into one revision, instead search the history for it:

```
$ git log -p -S 'funding' main composer.json
```

It should get you started to learn about the revisions that are related to "funding" in `composer.json` within the *main* branch.